# Postgres Shopping Database using Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

So I have just started to work with SQL and I have tested my script and is working very well when it comes to my database.

The database is used for shopping. What I mean by that is that I scrape a website that I love (Flowers etc) and then I collect each item that has been updated on the website and add it to my database if the product has not already been added in the database before (Reason why I have a checkIfExists function)

I also have different get Links, get Keywords functions and the reason I have

`getLinks` = Is to see if there has been added new page in the website that is not in my DB

`getBlackList` = In case they re-add same product and I don't want it to be too spammy with my logs then I can blacklist it inside the database.

`getAllKeywords` = Sometimes I want to filter for specific flowers where I have a function that checks whats the name of the product and then compare if those keywords matches from my database

The code I have written is working as I want and very proud of it and I do feel like I have done some steps abit too much. What I mean by that is that for every function I call `cur = self.database.cursor()` and `cur.close()` which maybe is not important or there is a newer way to handle this better. In my eyes I have a feeling I am missing something more.

I would appreciate all kind of help, even if I might have asked wrong question in Code review (its my first time and tried to read the description on how to write good) and as I mentioned before... I appreciate all kind of help! :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from datetime import datetime

import psycopg2


class DataBaseAPI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.database = psycopg2.connect(host="test",
                                         database="test",
                                         user="test",
                                         password="test"
                                         )

    def checkIfExists(self, store, link):
        try:
            cur = self.database.cursor()
            sql = f"SELECT DISTINCT link FROM public.store_items WHERE store='{store.title()}' AND visible='yes' AND link='{link}';"
            cur.execute(sql)
            cur.close()
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)
            return False

        if cur.rowcount:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def addProduct(self, product):

        if self.checkIfExists(store=product["store"], link=product["url"]) is False:

            link = product["url"],
            store = product["store"],
            name = product["name"],
            image = product["image"]
            visible = "yes"

            cur = self.database.cursor()
            sql = f"INSERT INTO public.store_items (store, name, link, image, visible, added_date) VALUES ('{store}', '{name}', '{link}', '{image}', '{visible}', '{datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}');"
            cur.execute(sql)

            # # Commit the changes to the database
            self.database.commit()

            # Close communication with the PostgreSQL database
            cur.close()

            return True
        else:
            return False

    def getAllLinks(self, store):
        cur = self.database.cursor()
        sql = f"SELECT DISTINCT link FROM public.store_items WHERE store='{store.title()}' AND visible='yes';"
        cur.execute(sql)
        cur.close()
        return [link[0] for link in cur.fetchall()]

    def getBlackList(self, store):
        cur = self.database.cursor()
        sql = f"SELECT DISTINCT link FROM public.store_items WHERE store='{store.title()}' AND visible='no';"
        cur.execute(sql)
        cur.close()
        return [link[0] for link in cur.fetchall()]

    def getAllKeywords(self, filtered_or_unfiltered):
        cur = self.database.cursor()
        sql = f"SELECT DISTINCT keyword FROM public.keywords WHERE filter_type='{filtered_or_unfiltered}';"
        cur.execute(sql)
        cur.close()
        return [keyword[0] for keyword in cur.fetchall()]
```

I think thats pretty much it. Just a simple Add and Get database :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before anything, read on SQL parameterization and avoid concatenating or interpolating variables directly in SQL statements. Otherwise you open your application to SQL injection and inefficiencies. The module, `psycopg2`, has much support for parameterizations as their [docs indicate](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html).

Secondly, save `cur` as another `self.` attribute and handle cursor and connection closings in a `__del__` method. Also `public.` is the default schema in PostgreSQL and hence can be omitted from table names.

```py
from datetime import datetime

import psycopg2

class DataBaseAPI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.database = psycopg2.connect(host="test",
                                         database="test",
                                         user="test",
                                         password="test")

        self.cur = self.database.cursor()

    def checkIfExists(self, store, link):
        try:
            # PREPARED STATEMENT WITH %s PLACEHOLDERS
            sql = """SELECT DISTINCT link 
                      FROM store_items 
                      WHERE store=%s AND visible=%s AND link=%s;
                  """
            # EXECUTE WITH BINDED PARAMS
            cur.execute(sql, (store.title(), 'yes', link))

        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)
            return False

        if cur.rowcount:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def addProduct(self, product):
        if self.checkIfExists(store=product["store"], link=product["url"]) is False:
            link = product["url"],
            store = product["store"],
            name = product["name"],
            image = product["image"]
            visible = "yes"

            # PREPARED STATEMENT WITH %s PLACEHOLDERS
            sql = """INSERT INTO store_items (store, name, link, image, visible, added_date)
                     VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"""

            # EXECUTE WITH BINDED PARAMS
            cur.execute(sql, (store, name, link, image, visible,
                              datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))

            # Commit the changes to the database
            self.database.commit()

            return True
        else:
            return False

    def getAllLinks(self, store):
        # PREPARED STATEMENT WITH %s PLACEHOLDERS
        sql = """SELECT DISTINCT link
                 FROM store_items 
                 WHERE store=%s AND visible=%s;
              """

        # EXECUTE WITH BINDED PARAMS
        cur.execute(sql, (store.title(), 'yes'))

        return [link[0] for link in cur.fetchall()]

    def getBlackList(self, store):
        # PREPARED STATEMENT WITH %s PLACEHOLDERS
        sql = """SELECT DISTINCT link 
                 FROM store_items 
                 WHERE store=%s AND visible=%s;
              """

        # EXECUTE WITH BINDED PARAMS
        cur.execute(sql, (store.title(), 'no'))

        return [link[0] for link in cur.fetchall()]

    def getAllKeywords(self, filtered_or_unfiltered):
        # PREPARED STATEMENT WITH %s PLACEHOLDERS
        sql = """SELECT DISTINCT keyword 
                 FROM keywords 
                 WHERE filter_type=%s;
              """
        # EXECUTE WITH BINDED PARAMS
        # (INNER PARENS + COMMA IS NOT A TYPO BUT A ONE-ITEM TUPLE)
        cur.execute(sql, (filtered_or_unfiltered,))  
        
        return [keyword[0] for keyword in cur.fetchall()]

    def __del__(self):
        # CLOSE OBJECTS
        self.cur.close()
        self.database.close()
```